# NetwrokX nx.add_edges_from() how to add a one way edge?

Tags: networking, graph, jupyter-notebook, networkx

I am attempting to a build a graph of a distribution network. In the past I have used add_edges_from() to be able to import all of the graph in 1 step. I have several 1-way edges but when I am importing some of them they are importing reversed. Is there a way to direct jupyter to make an edge a one way edge. Specifically:
RIC -> MAR, VB->RIC, VB->WDC, AND RIC-> NCA & NCA-> VB Should be 2-way with different capacities.

```
import networkx as nx
D = nx.Graph()
edges= [('CD', 'MAR', {'capacity': 200}), 
        ('CD', 'RIC', {'capacity': 200}), 
        ('CD', 'NCA',{'capacity': 150}), 
        ('RIC', 'NCA', {'capacity': 145}), 
        ('NCA', 'RIC', {'capacity': 125}), 
        ('RIC', 'MAR', {'capacity': 100}), 
        ('RIC', 'WDC', {'capacity': 230}), 
        ('NCA', 'WDC', {'capacity': 100}), 
        ('VB', 'RIC', {'capacity': 275}), 
        ('MAR', 'WDC', {'capacity': 150}), 
        ('NCA', 'VB', {'capacity': 200}), 
        ('VB', 'NCA', {'capacity': 175}), 
        ('VB', 'WDC', {'capacity': 50})]
D.add_edges_from(edges)
print('Number of Nodes:',D.number_of_nodes())
print('Nodes:', list (D.nodes))
print( 'Number of Edges',D.number_of_edges())
for i in range(len(D.edges)):
    print('Edge:',list(D.edges)[i] ,list(D.edges.values())[i])
maxflow=nx.maximum_flow(D,'CD','WDC')
print('Flow from each node (From Node: {Node reciveing: Flow})')
for key in maxflow[1]:
    print(key, ' : ', maxflow[1][key])
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Use [nx.DiGraph](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html#digraph-directed-graphs-with-self-loops), Directed Graphs instead of nx.Graph, Undirected Graphs.

```
import networkx as nx
D = nx.DiGraph()
edges= [('CD', 'MAR', {'capacity': 200}), 
        ('CD', 'RIC', {'capacity': 200}), 
        ('CD', 'NCA',{'capacity': 150}), 
        ('RIC', 'NCA', {'capacity': 145}), 
        ('NCA', 'RIC', {'capacity': 125}), 
        ('RIC', 'MAR', {'capacity': 100}), 
        ('RIC', 'WDC', {'capacity': 230}), 
        ('NCA', 'WDC', {'capacity': 100}), 
        ('VB', 'RIC', {'capacity': 275}), 
        ('MAR', 'WDC', {'capacity': 150}), 
        ('NCA', 'VB', {'capacity': 200}), 
        ('VB', 'NCA', {'capacity': 175}), 
        ('VB', 'WDC', {'capacity': 50})]
D.add_edges_from(edges)
nx.draw_networkx(D)
```

Output:

[image]